# using jquery and slick js is a trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, slick.js

i'm built a page with bootstrap, jquery , and slick.. but i have a problem while generate dynamic data .. if im using static data, working fine.

my js

```
$.post(api + "/api.php?c=newslide", function (response) {
        var arr = $.parseJSON(response);
        var trHTML = '';
        $.each(arr, function (ix, nilai) {

            trHTML += '<li><div class="post-style2" itemscope itemType="http://schema.org/BlogPosting"><div class="post-thumb2"><img itemprop="image" src='+arr[ix].img+' alt=""/></div><div class="post-detail2"><div class="cat"><a itemprop="url" href="#" title="">'+arr[ix].category+'</a></div><h3 itemprop="headline"><a itemprop="url" href="#" title="">'+arr[ix].title+'</a></h3><div class="date"><ul><li><a itemprop="datePublished" content="December-29-2014" href="#" title="">'+arr[ix].publish_date+'</a></li></ul></div><p itemprop="description">'+arr[ix].content+'</p></div></div></li>'

        });
        $('#sliderfirst').html(trHTML);

    });
```

and at HTML

```
<div class="slider-post">
<ul id="sliderfirst" class="slider-for">
</ul>
</div>
```

if im using static data / typing manually at HTML , the slide is working, but , if im using dynamic data, the slide is stopped working, and going to horizontally .. (same if using Vue.js for generate / getting data).

check at console.log , but nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic data"?  What specifically isn't working?  In what specific way does the "static" version differ from the "dynamic" version?

Comment: @David see at my JS , im getting data from JSON using PHP for MySql

Comment: And what is that data?  How does it differ from the "static" data?  What HTML does this code produce with the data?  How is it different from the "static" data's HTML?  You need to provide debugging information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wrap you dynamic image source variable in double quotes inside a string.

So, try to change this part:

```
'...<img itemprop="image" src=' + arr[ix].img + ' alt=""/>...'
```

To this

```
'...<img itemprop="image" src="' + arr[ix].img + '" alt=""/>...'
```

Answer (score -1):

solved

just moved from index into my js. thanks for all

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: false,
      slide: 'li',
      fade: false,
      asNavFor: '.slider-nav'

    });
```